# Why does splitting strings give ArrayOutOfBoundsException in Spark 1.1.0 (works fine in 1.4.0)?

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I'm using Spark 1.1.0 and Scala 2.10.4.

I have an input as follows:

```
100,aviral,Delhi,200,desh
200,ashu,hyd,300,desh
```

While executing:

```
sc.textFile(inputFile).keyBy(line => line.split(',')(2))
```

Spark gives me `ArrayOutOfBoundsException`. Why?

Please note that the same code works fine in Spark 1.4.0. Can anyone explain the reason for different behaviour?

Comment: Can you check if all lines have appropriate number of elements, say 3 that would correspond to `(2)` in the Q? A quick scan with `filterNot` can give you an answer.

Comment: According to input file I have specified in the question... I dont see a data problem .

Answer (score 1):

## It works fine here in Spark 1.4.1 / spark-shell

Define an rdd with some data

```
val rdd = sc.parallelize(Array("1,abc,2,xyz,3","4,qwerty,5,abc,4","9,fee,11,fie,13"))
rdd: org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[String] = ParallelCollectionRDD[0] at parallelize at <console>:21
```

Run it through `.keyBy()`

```
rdd.keyBy( line => (line.split(','))(2) ).collect()
res4: Array[(String, String)] = Array((2,1,abc,2,xyz,3), (5,4,qwerty,5,abc,4), (11,9,fee,11,fie,13))
```

Notice it makes the key from the 3rd element after splitting, but the printing seems odd.  At first it doesn't look correctly tupled but this turns out to be a printing artifact from missing any quotes on the string.  We could test this to pick off the values and see if we get the line back:

```
 rdd.keyBy(line => line.split(',')(2) ).values.collect()
 res12: Array[String] = Array(1,abc,2,xyz,3, 4,qwerty,5,abc,4, 9,fee,11,fie,13)
```

and this looks as expected.  Note that there are only 3 elements in the array, and the commas here are within the element strings.

We can also use `.map()` to make pairs, like so:

```
rdd.map( line => (line.split(',')(2), line.split(',')) ).collect()
res7: Array[(String, Array[String])] = Array((2,Array(1, abc, 2, xyz, 3)), (5,Array(4, qwerty, 5, abc, 4)), (11,Array(9, fee, 11, fie, 13)))
```

which is printed as Tuples...

Or to avoid duplicating effort, maybe:

```
def splitter(s:String):(String,Array[String]) = {
    val parsed = s.split(',')
    (parsed(2), parsed)
}

rdd.map(splitter).collect()
res8: Array[(String, Array[String])] = Array((2,Array(1, abc, 2, xyz, 3)), (5,Array(4, qwerty, 5, abc, 4)), (11,Array(9, fee, 11, fie, 13))
```

which is a bit easier to read.  It is also slightly more parsed, because here we have split the line into its separate values.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is you have a blank line after 1st row - splitting it does not return an Array containing necessary number of columns.

```
 1,abc,2,xyz,3
<empty line - here lies the problem>   
 4,qwerty,5,abc,4
```

Remove the empty line.

Another possibility is that one of the rows does not have enough columns. You can filter all rows that does not have the required number of columns (be aware of possible data loss though).

```
sc.textFile(inputFile)
.map.(_.split(","))
.filter(_.size == EXPECTED_COLS_NUMBER)
.keyBy(line => line(2))
```

Comment: This shouldn't be downvoted.  These are valid issues that explain the error.  Maybe there's a syntax error on your suggested code.  You might need to rearrange or add parenthesis to prevent early evaluation or maybe it is fine, I haven't checked.

Comment: Yeah, I wish the downvoter would explain why my reasoning is incorrect for the sake of the answer quality. I will check this code once again when I will have some time.